# manipulating Dataframe data (finding a row in an index with the highest items)

Tags: python, pandas

```
dataframe_max = scripts_practices_clean.groupby(by=['post_code_x','bnf_name']).max(axis=1)
```

I have groupby-ed my data to produce a dataframe that looks like this:
https://i.snag.gy/GJLnOp.jpg

I have a coding question that requires me to calculate the proportions for the most common 'bnf_names' for each postal code.

Formatting my answer as a list of tuples:`[(post_code, bnf_name, total)]`. 
This first requires me to calculate the total items of each 'bnf_name' prescribed in each 'post_code'.

Question 1:

I've managed to get the `post_code` as the index, but am clueless as to how to find the `bnf_name` with the highest items for each `post_code`. (I should have 100 tuples of (post_code, bnf_name, total)).

Question 2:

How do I extract the data from my dataframe into a tuple?

Much help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

*Question 1: most common bnf_names by totaling items column for each postal code*

```
## First group by post post_code and bnf_name and sum the total number of items
x = df.groupby(['post_code', 'bnf_names'])['items'].sum().reset_index()

## Now sort them by the summed up values in the items column
y = x.sort_values(['items'], ascending = False).groupby(['post_code', 'bnf_names']).head(1)

## Drop all the duplicates except the first occurrence post_code wise
z = y.drop_duplicates(['post_code'], keep = 'first')
```

The `z` dataframe should now have your required result using which you can get your tuple.

*Question 2: Convert dataframe to tuple*

```
tup = [tuple(i) for i in z.values]
```

Comment: Sorry, but the question asks for "most common" as in the bnf_names with the highest items

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, updated it, please check. Should work now.